# Static single page site, removing anchors

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, anchor

I have a static single page website, however I'm trying to figure out how to "link" to each section of the page giving a unique URL and being able to show in the browser history.

I don't even know where to start - I tried .htaccess with:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule   ^services/?$ /index.html#services [NE,R]
```

However the URL updates with the # rather than keeping the /services/ link (although it does redirect correctly).

Clearly this isn't the solution because

- It adds the hash back to the URL
- Does not show in users browser history properly

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the R flag if you want an internal redirection :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^services/?$ /index.html#services [NE,L]
```

Comment: When I replace R with L going to the url.com/services/ doesn't go to the services section of the page anymore. It doesn't bring an error either just loads top of the page.

Comment: @Matt The rule is working fine if it loads the page.

Comment: Nope, just copy pasted what you had there.